# Cannot use csvSftpConnector with schema registry

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I'm trying to configure a standalone producer to read csv files from a sftp server and send data to a **topic** on the cloud.

So far I succeeded in reading my csv data from the file and parsing it according to my **value.schema**.

But now instead of using a fixed configuration schema, I'd like to use the schema registry. So I configured an AVRO schema for my test topic on the confluent cloud, generated the API key/secret and updated my config files.

I can see that connection is working fine, no authentication errors, via cli I can access the test schema, but when I try to run the producer I get the following error:

```
[2021-09-20 16:39:53,442] INFO SftpCsvSourceConnectorConfig values: 
batch.size = 1000
behavior.on.error = IGNORE
cleanup.policy = NONE
csv.case.sensitive.field.names = false
csv.escape.char = 92
csv.file.charset = UTF-8
csv.first.row.as.header = false
csv.ignore.leading.whitespace = true
csv.ignore.quotations = false
csv.keep.carriage.return = false
csv.null.field.indicator = NEITHER
csv.quote.char = 34
csv.rfc.4180.parser.enabled = false
csv.separator.char = 44
csv.skip.lines = 0
csv.strict.quotes = false
csv.verify.reader = true
empty.poll.wait.ms = 250
error.path = /home/alberto/opt/confluent-6.2.0/sftp2/error
file.minimum.age.ms = 0
finished.path = /home/alberto/opt/confluent-6.2.0/sftp2/finished
input.file.pattern = .*.csv
input.path = /home/alberto/opt/confluent-6.2.0/sftp2/data
kafka.topic = testSchema
kerberos.keytab.path = 
kerberos.user.principal = 
key.schema = {"name" : "com.example.users.UserKey","type" : "STRUCT","isOptional" : true,"fieldSchemas" : {"material" : {"type" : "STRING","isOptional" : true}}}
parser.timestamp.date.formats = [yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss, yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss]
parser.timestamp.timezone = UTC
processing.file.extension = .PROCESSING
proxy.password = [hidden]
proxy.username = 
schema.generation.enabled = false
schema.generation.key.fields = []
schema.generation.key.name = defaultkeyschemaname
schema.generation.value.name = defaultvalueschemaname
sftp.host = 192.168.1.6
sftp.password = [hidden]
sftp.port = 22
sftp.proxy.url = 
sftp.username = user
timestamp.field = 
timestamp.mode = PROCESS_TIME
tls.passphrase = [hidden]
tls.pemfile = 
tls.private.key = [hidden]
tls.public.key = [hidden]
value.schema = 

   ...
   Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Both configs key.schema and value.schema must be set if schema.generation.enabled is false, but key.schema was not null and value.schema was null.
    at io.confluent.connect.sftp.source.SftpSourceConnectorConfig.validateSchema(SftpSourceConnectorConfig.java:181)
    at io.confluent.connect.sftp.source.SftpSourceConnectorConfig.<init>(SftpSourceConnectorConfig.java:121)
    at io.confluent.connect.sftp.source.SftpCsvSourceConnectorConfig.<init>(SftpCsvSourceConnectorConfig.java:157)
    at io.confluent.connect.sftp.SftpCsvSourceConnector.start(SftpCsvSourceConnector.java:44)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doStart(WorkerConnector.java:184)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.start(WorkerConnector.java:209)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doTransitionTo(WorkerConnector.java:348)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doTransitionTo(WorkerConnector.java:331)
    ... 7 more
```

If I set schema.generation.enabled to true, it seems that it creates an empty schema:

```
value.schema = {"type":"STRUCT","isOptional":false,"fieldSchemas":{}}
```

and then I get:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Failed to access Avro data from topic testSchema : Schema being registered is incompatible with an earlier schema for subject "testSchema-value"; error code: 409; error code: 409
```

as if it's trying to register a schema, except that it's not what I want, I just need to fetch the schema from the registry and use it.

If anyone need any addition information regarding the configuration I'll happy to provide.

Comment: A Source Connector uses a producer. A producer will register a schema in the registry, not use any existing one. You'll need to delete any "empty" one that was previously created if manually writing your own

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer, that's it. If you want you can write your comment as an answer.